# Getting error "deprecated name" and expression expected. ts(1109)

Tags: reactjs, expression, deprecated

I am getting errors in my react component. I am a very beginner at react. It shows that the name is deprecated and the expression expecting (;). I am following a video in which everything is going well but an error is occurring in my case.

```
import React from 'react'
const UpdatedComp = OriginalComp =>{
    class NewComp extends React.Component{
        render(){
            returns <OriginalComp name = "The user"/>
        }
    }
    return NewComp;
}
export default UpdatedComp;
```

Comment: the returns keyword should be return. You have have a typo. If you are just learning react then you should use functional comonents its easier and more used these days. React docs with functional  aproach https://beta.es.reactjs.org.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after a while. Though thank you. It's been only 2 days starting learning react. For that reason I am facing many difficulty understanding it. I will for sure check out React docs. Thanks.